# Navbar nav-link href reference not returning full string

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the full href string off of my nav-link item but it's not working. Here is my menu:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="menuClient" href="Modules/Clients/ClientDashboard.aspx" value="Client" runat="server">Client</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="Modules/Suppliers/SuppliersDashboard.aspx" value="Suppliers" id="ddSuppliers" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server">
                Suppliers
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ddSuppliers">
                <a class="dropdown-item" style="z-index: 999;" id="ddAddNewSupplier" runat="server" href="Modules/Supplier/AddSupplier.aspx">Add Supplier</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" style="z-index: 999;" id="ddSupplierList" runat="server" href="Modules/Supplier/List.aspx">Supplier List</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm getting the href attribute in this jQuery function:

```
$('#navbarNavDropdown').find('.nav-link').each(function () {
      var curr = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(curr);
});
```

And whenever I'm clicking on a menu instead of getting the full href I only get the current page. For example, if I click on client,

`($this).attr('href');`

gives me ClientDashboard.aspx instead of Modules/Clients/ClientDashboard.aspx.

How can I get the full string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1ge9Lsqd/  I'm unable to replicate your issue

Comment: it's missing the <nav class="navbar"> </nav> around the full code, for some reason I can't get that to show up on my code - sorry, kinda new to posting here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/27wL3nrc/  same results.  Unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: the issue only happens when you click on a menu item - since clicking there takes you to a 404 you can't replicate it

Comment: You're missing the point.  You're claiming that `attr('href')` is returning only the Name.aspx, not the full attribute.  My fiddle proves otherwise.  You may have an issue else where, but it is not with a defective `attr()` method

Comment: I understand your point. When I am in the home page of my application, every href returns its full string. When I click on a menu item, for example clients, every menu item will return its full string except for clients, which will return ClientDashboard.aspx.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information, and try to make a working example of your issue.  Because as it stands, what you're saying is an issue is not being demonstrated.

Comment: In fact clicking "Clients" in the fiddle tries to navigate to "fiddle.jshell.net/27wL3nrc/show/Modules/Clients/ClientDashboard.aspx1", which is the full path based off of the href.  https://i.imgur.com/YL7ZEKo.jpg

Comment: Yes, but ($this).attr('href') does not return the full string... I have no issues with my site navigation.

Comment: Yes, it does.  The fiddle proves it.  It returns the full string that is in the attribute.  It does not return the full href that goes into the browser url, if that is what you are actually after

Comment: @andremello based off of the work Taplar has done the next step for you would be to slowly remove code on your page and then test the to see if the URL value returns correctly. Chances are its something else on the page effecting your code.